# Mailgun SDK unable to find required classes (php)

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm trying to use the Mailgun API SDK to send emails from my test server. I downloaded the SDK itself as I am not currently using Composer.

However, when I try to instantiate a Mailgun object, I get this error:

> Fatal error:  Class 'Mailgun\Connection\RestClient' not found in /var/www/mysite.xyz/www/inc/libs/Mailgun/Mailgun.php on line 38

Which I fixed by adding `require "Connection/RestClient.php";` to the Mailgun.php file. However, this in turn caused its own error.

> Fatal error:  Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in /var/www/mysite.xyz/www/inc/libs/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php on line 41

This is included in my includes.php, so for all pages.

```
#Mailgun php functions
require_once "libs/Mailgun/Mailgun.php";
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
```

Then, when I try to use this;

```
# First, instantiate the SDK with your API credentials and define your domain. 
$mg = new Mailgun\Mailgun("key-myactualkey");
$domain = "myactualdomain.xyz";
print "Email to send is ".$welcomeemail; #Never gets reached
```

It causes those fatal errors and the program grinds to a halt.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using composer which is easier then you might think. Just follow these instructions (locally, on your computer, where PHP should be installed):

https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/master/SharedHostInstall.md

Then upload all files generated to your server in a separate directory.

Then include the following lines to your script:

```
require 'your/path/to/these/files/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
```

Create a new Mailgun object like this:

```
$mg = new Mailgun("your-secret-key");
```

Comment: This would probably work, but I really like to keep my code as light as possible. I solved this by realising that using CURL directly would only take about five lines of much lighter code, so I used it instead,